# Не получается задать размер вектора через размер другого вектора

Tags: c++, vector, вектор

Мне нужно создать вектор, размер которого равен размеру другого вектора (а именно - вектора векторов и его элемента).
Получается ошибка "выражение должно иметь константное значение".

```
vector <vector <bool>> testB = { {1,0}, {0,0}, {1,0} };
    int nt1 = testB.size();
    int nt2 = testB[0].size();

    vector <int> atest  [nt1];
    vector <int> aatest [nt2];
```

Как вообще можно создать такие векторы? (или массивы, лишь бы где-то числа собрать, ы))

Comment: `vector <int> atest  [nt1];` объявляет массив объектов `vector <int>`. Вместо этого вам надо вызвать конструктор, принимающий исходный размер, или вызывать конструктор по-умолчанию и затем `resize`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
vector <vector <bool>> testB = { {1,0}, {0,0}, {1,0} };
int nt1 = testB.size();
int nt2 = testB[0].size();

vector <int> atest(nt1);
vector <int> aatest(nt2);
```

Comment: не обновил страницу, а после отправки увидел уже что кто-то ответил

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял, что вам нужно -

```
vector <vector <bool>> testB = { {1,0}, {0,0}, {1,0} };
int nt1 = testB.size();
int nt2 = testB[0].size();

vector <int> atest(nt1);
vector <int> aatest(nt2);
```